# How to store the values from a component that is reused so that I can use the values later?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following state:

```
state = {
    score:12
};
```

This particular component is reused multiple times therefore changing the state every time. I understand I can store the values independently by setting states for score1 and score2 respectively for each use of the component. But that way the code gets very large as this component involves lots of variables.

Is there a way to store the value of 'score' from all the uses of the component so that I can access them later, without setting states independently for each use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array and add to it the new value each time:

```
state = {
   score: []
}

//add score
setState({score: [newScore, ...this.state.score]})

//access latest updated score
this.state.score[0]
```

Comment: I'm using a range( slider); Only want to store the value in the array in which the slider settles. Now with your suggestion, it's storing all the values as I'm moving the slider.

Also, as I'm reusing the component, the score array is starting all over again. Any further suggestion. @AbdellahSabiri

Comment: Are you using onChange or onInput on the slider ?

Comment: Using onChange now and both onInput and onChange are providing the same output @AbdellahSabiri

Comment: I'm trying to use the same slider component 4 times to generate 4 different scores.  These 4 scores need to be added in the end. And, I want to show real time the change  in the sum of these 4 scores as I move any of these sliders. But here, as soon as I slide the second slide the array restarts and also I can only access the value of the last slider change.
@AbdellahSabiri